# How to check if any application is running on a Datagram Port?

Tags: datagram, radius, freeradius

I have a list of radius servers running on each Datagram Socket and have a list of these started radius servers available with me.
I have a requirement where i need to check if a particular server has been stopped and if stopped i need to restart it.
Below is the code I'm writing but not sure if this is the right way to do it.
Please advice.

....

```
int port = radiusServer.getAggregation()
                        .getAuthenticationPort();
                try {
                    // It will throw IO exception if no application is
                    // running
                    // on that
                    // port.
                    new DatagramSocket(port);
                    LOGGER.info(
                            "There is a server running on the Port number {}.",
                            port);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(
                            "Server is not running on port number {}.",
                            port);
                    startServer(radiusServer);
                }
```

....

Comment: {try {
      // It will throw IO exception if no application is
      // running
      // on that
      // port.
      DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
      ds.close();
      LOGGER.warn(
        "Server is not running on port number {}. Starting Server",
        port);
      startServer(radiusServer);
     } catch (IOException e) {
      if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
       LOGGER.debug(
         "There is a server already running on the Port number {}.",
         port);
      }
     }}

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works fine.

```
           try {
                    // It wont throw IO exception if no application is
                    // running
                    // on that
                    // port.
                    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
                    ds.close();
                    LOGGER.warn(
                            "Server is not running on port number {}. Starting Server",
                            port);
                    startServer(radiusServer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        LOGGER.debug(
                                "There is a server already running on the Port number {}.",
                                port);
                    }
                }
```